Installing macbook air 2019 drivers on Ubuntu 20.04
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my macbook air 2019 and I deleted the mac OS and for some reason the keyboard, touchpad and the wifi drivers do not wanna install, I've been trying for the past week and nothing happened so is there someone how had the same issue or if there is anyone who can help me it'll be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
